# Getting the outer boundary of a group of polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygonize

[image]I have an issue where I have feature classes of groups of zip codes in different sectors of the US that I have created. I want to be able to define the outer boundary of these groups so I can create a single shape file (one polygon). I was going to use this new polygon to clip the original file.

Is there a way to take many polygons and create a file that only shows the outer extent of the group? And how would I go about such an endeavor?

Comment: What software are you using? If you're going for a polygon feature that's normally called a hull polygon (convex or concave).

Comment: Hi, I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include whether your "feature classes of groups of zip codes" are points or polygons, please?

Comment: My zip codes are polygons. 'Minimum bounding geometry tool' and 'feature envelope to polygon tool' provided output polygons that exceed the extent of my group and I need the exact external boundary of of my zip code polygons. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a picture to show what you're after? Both of those tools are good suggestions, I'd like to see why they don't produce the required result and we can go from there.

Comment: Ok, dissolve was the key but now I have issues with not having selected all my polygons inside the area, however, I have faith I can edit my way through it. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: That explains it. Can you use the zip code as a dissolve field? That would eliminate the need for selection.

Comment: If you have the Advanced license and the 'holes' are all interior in your 1st dissolve result, then you can finish the task with Eliminate Polygon Part, because a hole is considered a part.  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000005q000000

Comment: Michael-I had to manually select the particular zip codes (from a map I couldn't upload, with rough accuracy)  to create the colored areas for which I'm looking to dissolve and with those, create my database. I think that answers your question. 
T. Wayne- That seems to be a more efficient way than I found: I edited the dissolved layer and 'patched' some new polygons over the holes and dissolved again. It was quick but a little messy. I will try your method next time.

Thanks again!

Comment: Ryan! I am trying to do exactly what you had done up to this point, that is, create polygons based on a collection of zip codes. Can you please tell me how you did it? I am using ArcGis 10. I'm at the ends of my wits here! Even basic instructions would help me immensely. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE Remy! Could you please post this as a [new question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead of as an answer? You can always include the link to this post in your question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 7):

In ArcGIS, use the [Minimum Bounding Geometry tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003q000000). You have several options of which kind of "encompassing" geometry you'd like to get back to clip against. Just remember to use `ALL` for the `group_option` parameter if you only want one geometry back.

**EDIT**: Based on how I understand what you're asking for now, I think [the dissolve tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000005n000000) is more appropriate. Dissolve on the same field that you are using to set up your class breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the [Feature Envelope to Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000038000000) tool will give you want you want.  If you need to merge features first, you can run the [Dissolve](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000005n000000) tool.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and quickest way I found is to clip a larger polygon (i.e. a county polygon) with your smaller polygon (i.e. a feature class of a group of voting districts, comprising one magisterial district, in my situation).  This will give you a polygon of the outer boundaries but remove the inner boundaries. You will have to merge the feature groups tho, first.  Then the clip will give that feature minus the inner boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate Polygons?
Combines polygons within a specified distance of each other into new polygons.

Comment: A good answer should include more detail on how the tool works and how it can be used to solve OP's question. Please edit to include a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dissolve geoprocessing tool:

[image]